# Factory bot creates incorrect data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Why is this test passing? I don't understand what the problem is: Factory bot or Rails?

Model:

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true

  validate :self_like

  private

  def self_like
    errors.add(:user, 'self-like') if votable.author_id == user_id
  end
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :vote do
    value { 1 }
    user
    association :votable, factory: :question
  end
end
```

If you output the tested object (pp vote), then all the attributes will be nil. In this case, it is possible to get the associated object (pp vote.votable)

```
describe 'validate :self_like' do
  let!(:vote) { build :vote }

  it "self-like" do
    vote.valid?

    expect(vote.errors[:user]).to include('self-like')
  end
end
```

Comment: Are votable.author_id and user_id nil?

Answer (score 0):

The way the factories are defined you don't specify that votable author and user match, so `votable.author_id == user_id` is going to be false.

The best solution I could think of is to update the votable author with an `after_build` hook and force it to match the user.

```
after(:build) do |vote|
  vote.votable.update!(author: vote.user)
end
```